# developing on vagrant box

Tags: php, virtual-machine, vagrant, development-environment

I've been running into more and more prepackaged vagrant boxes for developing in various environments. This is really cool, since it lets me start or stop a VM with the proper packages installed and collaborate with a team without messing around on my dev machine.

However I'm still confused by how best to develop on the VM. I know I can symlink files from my local machine to the VM. For example, if I link my `/GIT_PROJECTS/` directory into the vagrant box, I still need to then re-symlink a bunch of directories to various places within the VM via `vagrant ssh`, or else edit files locally on my dev machine then copy all files from the shared directory to their proper home within the VM.

NOTE: most projects I'm working on are either Ruby on Rails, or PHP frameworks like Laravelle that have their own directory structures and may not completely match up with the git repository's structure.

I can't simply do a `subl .` from within the VM to open sublime or use my normal IDE on the VM's files.

Maybe I just need to get better with `vim`, but I'm curious how others do it-- is there a best practice for developers working on VMs to use their "local" IDEs or GUI dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

Every major tech we have has a Vagrantfile in it, with a puppet manifest. It syncs the local dir to /opt/something, then runs puppet.

I personally use vim, make changes, then restart the app, etc. Any changes locally will be seen in the VM since VBox uses synced directories. Coworkers use sublimetext, etc with no issues. I'm not exactly sure how yours differs from this, but my motto is sync your git dir to the VM, and use puppet/config management for the rest, that way if you destroy the box, your left with commitable changes.